# Draw on a video and save with the drawn values

Tags: android, video, canvas, surfaceview, textureview

I am trying to draw on a video and record those things in android. I tried it in FFMPEG but it was slow processing. Any other way to make video faster?

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", mVideoFile, "-i", mOverlayFile, "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=1.0", "-strict", "experimental", "-r", Integer.toString(videoComposeVO.getFrameRate()), "-crf", "24", "-tune", "fastdecode", "-bufsize", "1000k", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-threads", "0", "-q", "4", "-movflags", "faststart", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-an", mOutputFile};
```

Comment: Can you please post your code or method what you are doing in FFMPEG ?

Comment: This command takes too much time for processing                         
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", mVideoFile, "-i", mOverlayFile,
                        "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=1.0", "-strict", "experimental",
                        "-r", Integer.toString(videoComposeVO.getFrameRate()), "-crf", "24", "-tune", "fastdecode", "-bufsize", "1000k", "-preset", "ultrafast",
                        "-threads", "0", "-q", "4", "-movflags", "faststart", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-an", mOutputFile};